# Style the rounded header

Tags: css, html, css-shapes

Is there any way to style this rounded header? I got stuck. Right now i cant set the white background.

**Update #1:**

My header html code:

How it looks like now:

I used bootstrap with custom css.

**Update #2:** 
As Eirenaios recommended:
![enter image description here][3]

**Update #3.** 
I fixed it myself by styling the background header and add it in css.

I have to remove images bc it belongs to my clients.

Comment: Please update the question with the code you've done so far.

Comment: You're going to have to show us what you've got so far to get any help with this one.

Comment: I updated it. Please check it. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinNguyen the code needs to be in the question itself. Plase see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It updated the post. Please check it.

Comment: @KevinNguyen you obviously didn't make an MCVE, you just dumped your code which isn't considered as good practice and not a good way of getting an answer. This said, check this http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/kytcuk9e/

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can** just replace image with below image
**roundhead.png**

[image]

and change css

```
#home-round {
  background:roundhead.png;
  height: 51px;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}    

header {
      background: #fff;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

> It will surely give u your desired outcome.

---

#### What I have done!

[image]

Comment: It doesnt wor for me.